# sudo gedit Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, gedit

I have a VPS on which I am attempting to install pure-FTPd via a root SSH account on a remote machine.  I have already installed gedit and have gotten to the stage where I need to edit a config using gedit with the following command `sudo gedit /etc/inetd.conf`

However doing do results in...

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(gedit:6155): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

I am a newbie at linux, please help, thanks

Comment: you are using an SSH terminal connection, right? just text? if so, you want to use a text-based text editor like `nano` or `pico` or `vi`. if you are actually in a gnome session try using `gksu` or `gksudo` instead of sudo. gksu/gksudo are the same as sudo, but made for graphical sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gedit is a graphical editor. However, SSH is a strictly **NON**-graphical interface. Therefore, use a text-based editor like nano or vim.

For example:

```
sudo vim /etc/inetd.conf
```